# Sleuth's trace ID in Logbook logs, on reactor netty - howto?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty

Some time ago, I was looking for a solution to propagate sleuth's trace IDs in [zalando's logbook](https://github.com/zalando/logbook) logs and found a solution - [#1690](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1690), that works.

However, mentioned [ReactorNettyHttpTracing](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/main/reactor-netty-http-brave/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/brave/ReactorNettyHttpTracing.java) is now deprecated, and I could not figure out how to inject suggested [Micrometer Tracing](https://micrometer.io/docs/tracing).

Is it really "proper" approach, still in SpringBoot 2.7.x with spring-cloud-sleuth 3.1.x, to use [Micrometer Tracing](https://micrometer.io/docs/tracing)?

If yes, could someone help me out with such integration / pointing to potential docs or examples?

*(note: adding SO question, as suggested in https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty new issue template)*

Comment: Open an issue in Reactor Netty with an example so that we can play with it and see what we can provide (or we may need to contact logbook maintainers)

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva thx :) I originally took your comment from template to go to SO:

<!--- /!\ Questions should be asked on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor-netty) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactor-netty). -->

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/2581) addresses same topic.